# Custom fonts in Qute Template Quarkus

Tags: html, css, quarkus, quarkus-qute

I want to use the Open Sans font to create a pdf using qute template engine in quarkus. The code I have used is this, but it always fallsback using sans-serif. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have also tried using @link within the style tags and it just fails when trying to render the pdf.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0 20px;
            font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
            color: #031434;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        th,
        td {
            padding: 8px 20px;
            text-align: left;

        }

        thead {
            background-color: #F7F8F9;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 500;
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }

        tr {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        td {
            font-weight: 400;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #E9EAED;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Payment list</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="main">
        <table>
            <thead >
            <tr>
                <th>Processed date</th>
                <th>Reference number</th>
                <th>Total amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {#if !payments.isEmpty}
                {#for item in payments}
                    <tr >
                        <!-- This is where the dynamic cells will be inserted -->
                        <td>{item.processedDateString}</td>
                        <td>{item.paymentReferenceNumber}</td>
                        <td>{item.totalAmountString}</td>
                    </tr>
                {/for}
            {/if}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using this inside style

```
@font-face {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        src: url("../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    }
```

[image]

EDIT

This is the code I used to renderize the html

```
 public ByteArrayInputStream createClaimDetailReport(ClaimDetails claim) {
    ClaimsPdfData claimsPdfData = new ClaimsPdfData();
    List<ClaimDetails> claims = new ArrayList<>();
    claims.add(claim);
    addClaimFormattedDateFromClaimDate(claims);
    claimsPdfData.setClaims(claims);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        String xdata = htmlToXhtml(insertClaimsValuesHtml(claimsPdfData, false));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xdata);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(byteArrayOutputStream);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        LOG.error("Error creation pdf ", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private String insertClaimsValuesHtml(ClaimsPdfData claimsPdfData, boolean list) {

    String data;

    if (list) {
        claimsPdfData.setTemplate(claimListTemplate);
    } else {
        claimsPdfData.setTemplate(claimDetailTemplate);
    }

    data = templateService.getClaimPdfData(claimsPdfData);

    return data;
}

private static String htmlToXhtml(String html) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    return document.html();
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it, could you create a minimal example and add it please ?

Comment: How do create the pdf? I mean which tool do you use to turn the html doc into a pdf doc? Also does it render the font correctly if you open the rendered HTML file? It does not seem to be a qute-related problem though.

Comment: Hi, i added the code used to renderize the pdf. The first thing that is done is to convert the html to xml and then ItextRenderer is used to create the pdf